# Qual a maneira em que aplicações feitas em C# Windows Forms são atualizadas, tendo controle de versão?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Qual seria o passo a passo de tal atualização de maneira que o software após passar por alguma mudança ou atualização isso se reflita para os sistemas que tem o mesmo software?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Crie um projeto Windows Forms no seu Visual Studio:

***File -> New -> Project***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir a sua aplicação clique com o botão direito em cima do nome do seu projeto no meu suspenso vai até o item ***Properties*** (Propriedades do seu projeto).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir de agora são configurações bem básicas para que sua aplicação seja atualizada via internet.

Escolha ***Publish*** para tal configurações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na caixa de texto ***Publishing Folder Location*** vai ser configurado uma pasta local que é uma pasta que o meu servidor *IIS* tem configurado um Site (perceba que possui ftp e web server ainda para tal configuração, por exemplo, se sua pasta for remota pode ser configurado um FTP).

*Caminho da pasta:* `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Update`

Na caixa de texto ***Installation Folder URL***, vai ser o endereço http contendo os arquivos necessárias para instalações e atualizações on-line do seu sistemas. *Obs*: em nosso caso vai ser feito no localhost da máquina mas, pode ser feito em um site normalmente seguindo a mesma idéia

*Caminho da URL:* `http://127.0.0.1/Update/`

Com essas duas configurações ficará a tela assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa mesma tela tem um botão ***Updates***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique no mesmo e habilite as configuração ***The application should check for updates*** e por enquanto só essa configuração basta para esse exemplo simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após deixar isso configurado confirme a tela no botão **OK**. Na tela anterior tem o botão **Publish Now** que nesse momento deverá ser clicado para que tenha um build e publish succeeded.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Instalar pela primeira vez via Web

Digite no seu navegador a URL: `http://127.0.0.1/Update/setup.exe` e sigas as instruções de instalação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a instalação que é simples o software já instalado na minha máquina com a tela que na verdade não tem nada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vou no projeto e vou adicionar nessa tela um botão e quero que após nova publicação seja feita uma atualização automática on-line da aplicação, sendo novamente clicado em **Publish Now** para gerar a nova versão.

Após isso clico novamente no programa e veja o que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode dar um *OK* ou *Ignorar* a nova atualização do software. Ao clicar em *OK* a tela sofrerá a atualização do botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ficaria a pasta de todas essas atualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece dele incrementar todas as vezes que damos um ***Publish Now***, porque a configuração *Automatically increment revision with each publish* está marcada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Referência*

- [Implantando aplicativos do Windows Forms com o ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms953320.aspx)
- [ClickOnce no Visual Studio 2010](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/18103/dotnet/clickonce-no-visual-studio-2010/)
- [ClickOnce Deployment for Windows Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/wh45kb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [ClickOnce Security and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t71a733d.aspx)
- [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Choosing a ClickOnce Deployment Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/71baz9ah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)