# Como executar um programa feito em c# na maquina do cliente?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Boa tarde pessoal, acabei de finalizar um sistema de venda em c#,estou testar o mesmo em uma outra maquina esta gerar erro, já instalei o .Net Framework 4.5  mas mesmo assim continua. Qual será o erro desta vez?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Clique em `Details` e poste o erro apresentado

Comment: Aproveite também e poste como você fez para levar o sistema para a máquina do cliente

Comment: Tá faltando esse PowerPacks na máquina do cliente.

Comment: Qual programa foi usado para gerar o instalador para o cliente?

Comment: Levei a penas a pasta Release e alterei o Directory nos 2 arquivo que tem a extensão .XML.

Comment: Talvez poderia experimentar isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15268/3635

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente será necessário instalar o Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs na máquina do cliente.

Na sua máquina não apresenta erro, por ser a máquina de desenvolvimento e nela a biblioteca ter sido instalada para o desenvolvimento da aplicação.

Baixe o executável abaixo e instale na máquina do cliente:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169

Comment: Muito antes deste deu testar este sistema, ja tivera feito um outro que na qual só precisei instalar o: .NETFramework, ReportView2008, Sql Server 2008, e funcionou normalmente, desta vez não sei o que esta a contecer

Comment: @AntónioMateta pode ter acontecido deste sistema que você fez antes não ter utilizado esta biblioteca

Comment: Utilizei as mesmas biblioteca que eu utilizei no sistema anterior